# Multiple plots in same page using grid.arrange()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to arrange 4 plots generated with ggplots stat_binhex() in the same pdf page.

```
densityplots<-lapply(1:breaks, function(i){
  dataplot<-ggplot(data,aes(x=data$A, y=data$B)) + stat_binhex() + xlim(-2,2) + ylim(-2,2)
  return(dataplot)
})
```

Using:

```
do.call(grid.arrange,c(densityplots,ncol=2))
```

I found the error:

```
Error in data.frame(x = c(-1.34537238683369e-05, 0.0053077854, 0.0011863784,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 11508, 9864
```

Datasets A and B used to generate plots differ in the number of rows. How can I plot them on the same page?

Thank you!

Comment: Never use `$` in `aes`. The syntax is `aes(x=A, y=B)` and ggplot then looks for these variables in the data.frame passed to the `data` argument.

Comment: Thank you Roland!Solved!